# DevOps: Combine AWS and GC into one website

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, google-cloud-platform, devops

Currently we have an older website running through a partner that host the site on AWS. We want to get more in control of the devops and are moving to Google Cloud. Now we have build a single page application that runs on Google Cloud, while the rest of the website is still running on AWS. Now we are stuck on combining the two. We have no control over the devops of our older website as the partner we work with is not flexible and only they have control.

We want to integrate the new single page app in the older website so that both run under the same domain, and all pages can be crawled by search engines. That's really important. It should not be noticeable to the user that our two sites were combined to one.

**Idea 1:**
An idea we had is to configure the new hosting at NGINX level to decide which URL's should go to which server (AWS or GC). However, we think there might be some advantages. The first one is latency, as all requests have to go through GC first and most of them will then by redirected to AWS server or to the CloudFront cache. Secondly, the outgoing traffic of GC will be big so costs will increase.

**Idea 2:**
Configure our older website on an application level (PHP) to redirect some of the URL's to the new single page application. In this case latency is again a problem as the website has to redirect certain traffic to the new GC server. In this case the PHP framework has bootstrapped so this increases the waiting time for the user as well.

**Idea 3:**
The old PHP website should load the new single page JS application, so the user is not redirected. Not sure how technically feasible this is.

Is there even a scenario in which this can work out and what will be the disadvantages? What extra latency can we expect if we redirect traffic from GC to AWS? Any feedback, tips or experiences to this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For Idea 1 and Idea 2 - the condition that old page and new SPA should be run at same domain isn't violated?

The second thing - as far I know in the past, google crawler treat different subdomains as separate pages (im not SEO expert) but if it is still true, your all SPA code must be served by old page server (however may be exist some trick to avoid this)

So may be Idea 3 is the best. Technically popular servers like apache/nginx (where is php code) can serve SPA code easily - just put compiled code in proper public directory and make link to this assets in old PHP app. You can also use GIT SUBMODULES to link your SPA code with your old app repo.

Comment: If you setup a load balancer (nginx or gce load balancer for example) you can define that different path redirects to a different server, and then they will be served from the same domain.

Comment: @rom I not have experience with load balancers, however it very interesting information in this context. So here we probably it is posibble to set up something like load-balancer which redirect SPA parh to GC and old php app to AWS...  (if that load-balancer can do such redirection)

Answer (score 0):

The seemingly obvious solution would be to point the domain at CloudFront and let CloudFront do the path-based route selection to fetch content from either CG or AWS based on cache behavior path patterns.   CloudFront is, after all, a globally-distributed reverse proxy as well as a cache, and has no requirement that the actual origin servers be in AWS. You'll pay for bandwidth out of GC to CloudFront, but only for cache misses.  This is similar to your #1 but puts the proxy in a better place... 100+ different places (the CloudFront edge locations).  It should have no negative latency impacts, and probably the opposite.

Comment: We are looking into this solution, but are unable to find how we can add some logic to redirect traffic to different servers based on the URL.

Would appreciate some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: With CloudFront, you specify *origins* -- the hostnames of the servers where CloudFront will send the requests -- and *cache behaviors*, each of which has a *path pattern* for the request paths it should match and the origin to which those requests should be sent.